# Include and inheritance in EF

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

i have model "User" that has collection of permissions of type "Permission":

```
    public class User : IUser<int>, IUser<string>
{
        public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions
        {
            get { return _permissions ?? (_permissions = new Collection<Permission>()); }
            set { _permissions = value; }
        }
     ...
}
```

i have inheritense:

```
public abstract class EntityPermission : Permission
    {        
        public AccessedEntity AccessedEntity { get; set; }
     ...
    }


public class ReadEntityPermission : EntityPermission
{
    public bool AllowAll { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

When i request User

```
DbSet.Include(c => c.Permissions)
```

I get permissions with all simple fields (AllowAll == true) of **ReadEntityPermission**, but property 
**AccessedEntity is null**.
Is there any way to load referenced properties of inherited children?

p.s.: dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled and dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled are true

Answer (score 1):

Include should be able to accept string as parameter. Try this:

```
DbSet.Include("Permissions.AccessedEntity")
```

UPDATE:
You cant access `AccessedEntity` property on Permission class because that class doesn't have that property. You must use `EntityPermission`. Like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<EntityPermission> Permissions
```

Comment: no, it didn't:  'Lk.Core.Security.Implementation.Permission' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'AccessedEntity'